# Overflow: scroll; only the y-axis whilst keeping x-axis visible

Tags: html, css

### Problem case

I'm trying to create a scrolling, fixed-height list with flyouts for each list item.

I've used `overflow-y: scroll;` so that it can be scrolled in the y-axis.

However when I also try to use `overflow-x: visible` (in order to display the overflowing flyouts) it seems to be ignored

### Code

#### Example 1 - List can be scrolled, but flyouts are clipped

As you can see, the flyouts (in-pink) are clipped

```css
.list {
  width: 72px;
  height: 132px;
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: lightgray;
}

.list li {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.flyout {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 64px;
  width: 128px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    Item 1
    <div class="flyout">Item 1 Flyout</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Item 2
    <div class="flyout">Item 2 Flyout</div>
  </li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
</ul>
```

#### Example 2 - List cannot be scrolled, flyouts displayed just fine

Removing `overflow-y: scroll` shows the flyouts just fine, but as expected, the list can no longer be scrolled height-wise.

```css
.list {
  width: 72px;
  height: 132px;
  overflow-x: visible;
  background: lightgray;
}

.list li {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.flyout {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 64px;
  width: 128px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    Item 1
    <div class="flyout">Item 1 Flyout</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Item 2
    <div class="flyout">Item 2 Flyout</div>
  </li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
</ul>
```

### A possible solution

I could of course make my `.list` have a width just enough so the flyouts don't overflow it.

I'd like to avoid that, as the list would be placed on top of a drawing canvas, thus it would block painting on the canvas via the mouse.

Using `pointer-events: none` so as not to block painting wouldn't work in this case as the pointer-events are necessary in order to detect the scroll-event for the list in the first place.

Comment: There's no CSS way (well there's JS workarounds...) to trick an element to pop out of an `overflow` parent.

Comment: What should happen with your fly-outs when they're i.e: (say in your image) at position 7 or 8? They should overflow-y right? in that case neither JS would help much

Comment: The flyouts are actually shown when hovering over the list items, so in that case the parent list-item of those flyouts must be in-view anyway

Comment: So only on item hover you want to show a flyout? Than there's a JavaScript way to do it!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan fire away - I think I could add a class on the list itself on hover of a list item to expands it's width so it fits the flyouts, then removing that same class on `mouseexit/mouseleave`

Comment: That could look extremely awful since the parent has overflow y scrollbars... imagine that parent changing width on LI hover... yuck

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Not sure it would look awful since I would only be changing the width while the scrollbars are displaying the height-axis. The list wouldn't have a background color so this size change wouldn't be visible

Comment: yes, it will be visible since it has the vertical scrollbars. Think about it.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'll give it a try - In the meantime feel free to post an alternative solution if you got one

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Maybe `overflow: hidden` when not hovered.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides do your flyouts need to be hoverable? i.e: if you hover it - it stays in place... (or you're using them just for Title info?)

Comment: @Oriol yes, I'm thinking...  the list has to be scrollable at any time....

Comment: @Oriol They will contain buttons, so they are interactible if that's what's you're asking - They stay in place until the user mouse-out's off them

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides edited my answer. Now the flyouts are hoverable.

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot force a child to exit an overflow parent - and control it's position - here's a
**jQuery solution**

jQuery creates dynamically a `<div class="flyout"></div>` element.
On LI hover it calculates the position and shows the flyout element.
The content is taken from the hovered LI `data-flyout` attribute:

```js
var $flyout = $("<div/>", {
  class: "flyout",
  appendTo: "body",
  hover: function(e) {
    $(this).toggle();
  }
});

$("[data-flyout]").hover(function(e) {

  var par = this.parentNode; // The overlfow parent element

  $flyout.css({
    left: this.offsetLeft + this.offsetWidth,
    top: this.offsetTop - par.scrollTop,
  }).html( this.dataset.flyout ).toggle();

});
```

```css
.list {
  width: 72px;
  height: 132px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: lightgray;
}

.list li {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

/* Created in "body" by jQuery */
.flyout {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:99999;
  display: none;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list">
  <li data-flyout="Item 1 Flyout">Item 1</li>
  <li data-flyout="Item 2 Flyout">Item 2</li>
  <li>No fly</li>
  <li data-flyout="Item 4 Flyout">Item 4</li>
  <li data-flyout="Item 5 Flyout">Item 5</li>
  <li data-flyout="Item 6 Flyout">Item 6</li>
  <li data-flyout="Item 7 Flyout">Item 7</li>
  <li data-flyout="Item 8 Flyout">Item 8</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to remove `position: relative`. Then the absolute positioned flyouts won't be restricted by `overflow`.

However, they won't scroll properly. You will need to trigger a relayout with JS.

```js
// Force relayout
var li = document.querySelector('li:last-child');
setInterval(function() {
  var parent = li.parentNode;
  var next = li.nextSibling;
  parent.removeChild(li);
  parent.insertBefore(li, next);
}, 60);
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
.list {
  width: 72px;
  height: 132px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: lightgray;
  margin: 0;
}
.list li {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.flyout {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 128px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      Item 1
      <div class="flyout">Item 1 Flyout</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      Item 2
      <div class="flyout">Item 2 Flyout</div>
    </li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Oh, this relayout method doesn't work on Chrome.

Comment: Really, Firefox tries really hard to reposition and repaint, while Chrome is just ehh

Comment: It might just be a Firefox bug. Calculating the position manually with JS is probably safer.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you could leverage something like [Superfish's vertical menu](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/examples/vertical/#a) and call it a day.

I agree with the above comments in that I don't see a pure CSS way to accomplish this.